# Python string scrambling

Tags: python

I want to Write a function that will take two string arguments and returns a list containing all the letters in both strings. All the letters returned should be lowercase and there should be no duplicate letters in the resulting list.

Example:

string_scramble('GraSS', 'grilled cheese')
Should return:

['g','r','s']

My Solution:

```
def string_scramble(string_one, string_two):

l = []

str_concat = string_one + string_two

str_lower = str_concat.lower()

str_space = sorted(str_lower.replace(" ", ""))

for i in str_space:

    if i not in l:

        l.append(i)

print(l)

return l
```

string_scramble("GraSS","grilled cheese")

This returns:

['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'r', 's']

Answer (score 2):

Use set intersection for this

```
>>> def string_scramble(s1, s2):
...     return set(s1.lower()) & set(s2.lower())
... 
>>> 
>>> string_scramble('GraSS', 'grilled cheese')
{'r', 's', 'g'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use convert them to `set`s and use `set.intersection`

```
def string_scramble(a, b):
    return set(str.lower(a)).intersection(str.lower(b))

string_scramble('GraSS', 'grilled cheese')
```

Returns

```
{'g', 'r', 's'}
```